# code outside functions not remembered and running every time

Tags: google-apps-script

I dont have a LOT of experience programming... so here is my doubt. I have written a large onEdit function on a google spreadsheet and placed some code outside that function, so it doesn't have to go through that code every time I edit a cell. its just variables containing the different sheeets, some important ranges, etc. I just want it to do run that script once and remember it.
the issue is that every time I edit something, that code reruns. I tried writing an "onOpen" function, but the variables created inside that function don't have scope outside the onOpen function. I also tried declaring the variables with no value, and then adding the values in an onOpen function that only runs once. it too doesn't work.
am I doing something wrong or is this just the way it works?

thank you!!

PS. I guess that you don't need the code because my questions goes beyond that. oh. and Im sorry for my english... Im not native.

Comment: That's just the way it works. You can use `PropertiesService` instead to store and remember variables.

Comment: variables that you declare outside of a function in a gs file are global and they get evaluated every time any function is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to what @TheMaster said, Google Apps Script is stateless. Meaning each invocation has to process the whole project. So when your `onEdit` function runs, it processes everything. For example:

```
var global = "hi";

function something(){ ... }

function onEdit()
{
    Logger.log(global);
    global = "bye";
}

something();
```

Every time the `onEdit` function triggers, it will run through all of the code. In this example, every time `onEdit` triggers, it'll set `global` to `hi`, run `something()`, and then run `onEdit()`.

I hope that make sense?